# Activity for result becomes just usual activity

Tags: android

I run activity for result(gallery) and waiting for the chosen image.
When the gallery is opened user presses home button, go to settings, change font style. Then resumes my application with holding home button(gallery still waiting for user choose image). When user selects photo, gallery becomes just usual activity and don't returns result for the waiting activity.

Comment: please post some code